# Issue with Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having an issue getting my recordset to work properly in the following code, and am unsure if its a personal runtime error of part of the inherent shabbiness of VBA. the code is as follows

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Dim dbInquiry As New ADODB.Connection

Dim rstVendor As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set dbInquiry = CurrentProject.Connection
    rstVendor.Open "Select * from Vendors Order By VendorName", dbInquiry, adOpenKeyset, _
    adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    
    Me.lstVendors = rstVendor!VendorNo
    Me.lstVendors.Requery
    Call readVendor

End Sub

Private Sub readVendor()
    
    Me.lblVendorNumber.Caption = rstVendor!VendorNo
    Me.lblVendorName.Caption = rstVendor!VendorName
    Me.lblVendorAddress.Caption = rstVendor!Address1
    Me.lblVendorCity.Caption = rstVendor!City & ", " & rstVendor!Prov
    Me.lblVendorPostal.Caption = rstVendor!PostCode

End Sub


Private Sub lstVendors_Click()

    rstVendor.MoveFirst
    rstVendor.Find "VendorNo = " & Me.lstVendors
    Call readVendor
    
End Sub
```

Now, the issue is with reading the database. When method readVendor is called on form load, it functions perfectly. when it is called on lst item click, i get Error 3021: Either BOF, EOF or record deleted. Any guidance very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: "and am unsure if its a personal runtime error of part of the inherent shabbiness of VBA" - always assume the bug is in your code first: 99.99% of the time it will be.

Comment: I agree with Mitch. VBA is not as robust as the .NET languages but your statement about "inherent shabbiness" implies that VBA is full of bugs, which is simply not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rstVendor.Find "VendorNo = " & Me.lstVendors

was something found? and/or is rstVendor still open?

Comment: Thats the entire code for the particular form i am working on. a simple listbox tied to labels to display information. But i think youre right, that seems to be the line where the code breaks for some reason. looking more into it now. much appreciated